# Graph of a Sine Function Increased on One Side

Tags: trigonometry, special-functions

If we want something looks like this sine wave, what is a function that will satisfy this: 
[image]

Further, how can we make this go both ways, meaning either 1) a sine wave staying the same at the bottom but going upwards linearly as it progresses (as shown) or 2) a sine wave staying the same at the bottom but going downwards linearly as it progresses?

I have tried, for example, $x/2(\sin x)$, which gives us a linear increase, but I want it to increase on the top while staying the same on the bottom.

Thanks!

Comment: Your link doesn't work, but try $f(x)(1+\sin x)$ where $f(x)$ is an increasing positive function [like say $\exp(x/20)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+exp%28x%2F20%29%281%2Bsin%28x%29%29+for+x%3D-20..20).

Answer (score 1):

Plot[ x (1 - Sin[x]), {x, -1, 45}, GridLines -> Automatic]
[image]

You can adjust the slope $m$ of envelope, time period etc as:

$$ y= m x \;(1- \sin \dfrac{2 \pi x }{\lambda})$$

To reflect about x-axis making it go down, equation can be changed as:

```
Plot[ x (-1 + Sin[x]), {x, -1, 45}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try $f(x)=x + x\sin x$, or something similar.

Comment: I have, and it works for increase. now how do I do decrease on the positive x-axis? In other words, I need a positive diminuting function. I used x for increasing, now I need decreasing.

Comment: I'd say something like $(10-x)(1+\sin x)$. Replace $10$ with the length you want...